# what is stringentity in android and its use

Tags: java, android, json, servlets

I am new to android , i am following this tutorial, i have found the code below , there he is converting json string to StringEntity. correct me if i am wrong StringEntity is used to pass the data,Headers like Accept,Content-type to Server.

```
            // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);



        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
        jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
        jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
        // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
.
.
.
```

and how do i get the data in the servlet/jsp ? Should i use getStream() or request.getParameter()

Comment: Go through this as well http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An entity whose content is retrieved from a string.

*StringEntity* is the raw data that you send in the request.

Server communicate using JSON, JSON string can be sent via StringEntity and server can get it in the request body, parse it and generate appropriate response.

we set all our unicode style,content type in this only

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(str,"UTF-8");
    se.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
```

For more help u can take reference this 
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html

As per your requirement I edit this for post method

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_src);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
httpclient.setParams(httpParameters);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(str,"UTF-8");
se.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(se); 



try
{
    response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();


    if(statusCode==200)
    {
        entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println("The response is" + responseText);   

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("error");;
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: how do i get the data in the servlet/jsp ? Should i use getStream() or request.getParameter()

Comment: what u want to do dude

Comment: like u want to get response from server through any API

Comment: as i am sending name,country and twitter as json(from android) in the StringEntity, now in the Serverside , how do i get the data(name,country,twitter) please see the code at 3rd point

Comment: see now its my post request method which i use

Comment: at response = httpclient.execute(httpPost); you are sending data to server, how do i get that data in Servlet ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49031/discussion-between-latif-mohammad-khan-and-bhanu-sharma)

Comment: Servlet  i dont knw dude sorry :)

Comment: servlet has doPost(...request ...response) method. If receiving text data you could create a BufferedReader from request.getReader() inside that method. Then use while-loop and readLine(), etc.

Comment: @BhanuSharma Thanks for this! So when passing a `StringEntity` via `HttpPost`, should the web-method have a type `String` parameter? Or should it have a type `Object` parameter and cast it to `String`? (*I am trying to call an ASP.NET .asmx web-service from Android*)

Comment: @lancampbell Yes u have to pass string in it.  public class StringEntity
extends AbstractHttpEntity
implements Cloneable java.lang.Object ↳ org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity ↳ 
 org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity Known Direct Subclasses UrlEncodedFormEntity UrlEncodedFormEntity An 
 entity composed of a list of url-encoded pairs. Class Overview
An entity whose content is retrieved from a string. Summary

Comment: StringEntity is depreciated. Please update the code.

Answer (score 2):

`StringEntity` is the raw data that you send in the request.

Most of the server communicate using JSON, **JSON string** can be sent via **StringEntity** and server can get it in the request body, parse it and generate appropriate response.

Accept,Content-type etc. are sent as the header of the request but `StringEntity` is content of it.

Header is not passed in `StringEntity`.

Comment: how do i get the data in the servlet/jsp ? Should i use getStream() or request.getParameter()

Comment: one upvote for convincing answer ...my doubt is then why there is setContentType in stringEntity.we can simply set the content type to http request right ! can you kindly explain me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I solved in **3 Steps** with **Jackson** in Netbeans/Glashfish btw.

1)Requirements :

some of the Jars I used :

```
 commons-codec-1.10.jar
 commons-logging-1.2.jar
 log4j-1.2.17.jar
 httpcore-4.4.4.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.4.jar
 avalon-logkit-2.2.1.jar
 javax.servlet-api-4.0.0-b01.jar
 httpclient-4.5.1.jar
 jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.6.4.jar
 jackson-databind-2.7.0-rc1.jar
 jackson-annotations-2.7.0-rc1.jar
 jackson-core-2.7.0-rc1.jar
```

If I missed any of the jar above , you can download from Maven here **http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core**

2)Example: Java Class where you send your Post.
First ,Convert with Jackson the Entity User to Json and then send it to your Rest Class.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import ht.gouv.mtptc.siiv.model.seguridad.Usuario;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


public class PostRest {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

         // 1. create HttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost 
        = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8083/i360/rest/seguridad/obtenerEntidad");


        String json = "";
        Usuario u = new Usuario();
        u.setId(99L);

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("id", u.getId());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        //json = jsonObject.toString();

        // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
         //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         //json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       json = mapper.writeValueAsString(u);

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");


        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        //inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

}


}
```

3)Example : Java Class Rest where you want to receive the Entity JPA/Hibernate .
Here with your MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) you recieve the Entity in this way :

> ""id":**99**,"usuarioPadre":null,"nickname":null,"clave":null,"nombre":null,"apellidos":null,"isLoginWeb":null,"isLoginMovil":null,"estado":null,"correoElectronico":null,"imagePerfil":null,"perfil":null,"urlCambioClave":null,"telefono":null,"celular":null,"isFree":null,"proyectoUsuarioList":null,"cuentaActiva":null,"keyUser":null,"isCambiaPassword":null,"videoList":null,"idSocial":null,"tipoSocial":null,"idPlanActivo":null,"cantidadMbContratado":null,"cantidadMbConsumido":null,"cuotaMb":null,"fechaInicio":null,"fechaFin":null}"

```
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;

    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    @Path("/seguridad")
    public class SeguridadRest implements Serializable {



       @POST
        @Path("obtenerEntidad")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public JSONArray obtenerEntidad(Usuario u) {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            LOG.fatal(">>>Finally this is my entity(JPA/Hibernate) which 
will print the ID 99 as showed above :" + u.toString());
            return array;//this is empty

        }
       ..
```

Some tips : If you have problem with running the web after using this code may be because of the  `@Consumes in XML` ... you must set it as `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`